# Android Self-Formatting in Response to Boot Mode

Tags: android, security, boot

I am attempting to enhance the security of my phone to make it "tamper-resistant." Specifically, I want the device to automatically format itself and erase data when connected to a computer. It's crucial that this process triggers when attempting to enter boot mode. If you have expertise in this area or can point me to valuable information sources, I would greatly appreciate it.

So far, I'm at the beginning of my Android journey, and I'm seeking information on which file I need to modify.